How can I split and remove partially overlapping faces without Mesh Boolean?
I have managed to remove overlapping faces using the Geometry Proximity node. However, for intersecting overlapping faces, I couldn't figure out how to partially remove the overlapping face without using the Mesh Boolean node, as it is too slow for my use case. I previously tried a setup where I used the Merge By Distance node since the vertices overlap perfectly. Unfortunately, that node does not split the face; it just merges the vertices without actually splitting the face. How can I remove the overlapping faces in such a way that it does not create a triangular missing face? The mesh needs to be closed.


If my requirement is not possible, perhaps there is a workaround to fill the missing triangular faces instead?

Maybe a bit peculiar to this case, but here, you can selectively triangulate the diamond mesh by proximity of quad faces, and then selectively delete the resultant triangular faces by the same proximity:

If you need a more general answer, I'll remove this one :)

